# Redesigning workflow of bidding application to reduce cognitive load

Tags: gui-design, web-app, workflow, windows-os

I am currently working on a pet project to port and redesign a native Windows-based app onto the web. It acts as a booking aggregator, providing a platform for service operators to bid, share, and trade jobs. A brief summary of the app is as follows:

[image]

- In order to acquire a job, the operator places a bid on a plot by selecting an item from the listview and clicking on the bid button.

[image]

- Once done, the operator's bid is placed in a queue, and details of their bid pops up in the positions box. The details of the job are not revealed to the user at this stage.

[image]

- Once the operator has been allocated a job, details of the job pop up in the job tray box. To maintain fairness in the system, the details of the job are revealed to the user at this stage.

I showed what I have designed so far to several taxi companies for feedback. Although they liked the idea, they told me that the overall UI/UX was rather cumbersome, and the whole process was mentally taxing especially when they processed more than 1 bid.

I still want to keep the bid-process-allocate process intact as it is an inherent part of the app. But I am not sure how I can design the workflow to make it more easier to use for the user. Keeping in mind that I am redesigning the app for the web, can anyone suggest how I can improve the workflow and design of the application to decrease the cognitive load on the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the application specifically for taxi companies? Further to that is the app for drivers receiving jobs?

If so, using location based jobs can make this process simpler. The operator only sees jobs relevant to them.

As an aside, the UI contains elements not used by the operator. If they are not needed, remove them.

Otherwise, could I get more info on the function of this bidding application?

Comment: Philip - thanks for taking the time to get back to me. The app is specifically for taxi drivers but it works in tandem with an app for drivers receiving jobs, as well as an app for customers booking jobs. It is possible to make it location based, wherein the operator only sees jobs relevant to them, based on where the plots in which they have drivers.

Comment: As that is the case, use location. I'm not going to give suggestions how the UI should be built, but location based jobs for taxi drivers makes the most sense. Relevant, timely & simplified.